# A debugger is attached but not configured to debug this unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, service, c++-cli

Yes, I know, I know, quite a few similar questions but the answers there just don't cut it for me. My setup might be a bit more complicated, maybe. The solution has two projects (both using .NET 4.5.2):

- a managed C# 64-bit (or possibly 32-bit) application,
- a C++/CLI Windows service, strictly 32-bit due to the SDKs used.

The service has an unhandled access violation crash when run, not in my code but somewhere in the depths of the SDK calling back to my code. The Event Viewer tells me it's in `ntdll.dll` but nothing more.

There are various ways to debug but the most convenient I found was to start the service as a standalone console application, with a `System::Diagnostics::Debugger::Launch()` call in its `Main()`. This allows me to attach it to the VS debugger. And it *is* running all right.

I start the main application now and go to the part where the crash occurs. No matter whether I started it under a second VS debugger or running directly from the UI (Windows offers to choose a debugger in the second case), the next dialog will be the usual error message (see title). However:

- the projects are set to debug mixed code (service), native included (main app),
- the main app has *Allow unsafe code* set (for unrelated reasons, but some answers suggest that this helps mixed code debugging, too),
- the debugger is set to handle *all* Win32 and C++ exceptions.

So the usual problems leading to this error are accounted for. What else might cause that I'm unable to debug this service?

Comment: A C++/CLI project requires the legacy managed debugging engine, it is not clear from the question whether you took care of that.  The new debugging engine misbehaves in several strange ways.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.  Life is considerably simplified when you leave it on permanently btw, the new engine is a nasty bag 'o bugs.

Comment: Both Managed and Native compatibilty modes are checked.

Comment: There are too many details missing.  "Windows offers to debug", does that mean you started the main app without a debugger?  Well, don't do that, too many ways to get that wrong, like selecting the running VS instance or picking the wrong debug engines.  Just start VS twice.

Comment: Either two VS's running or only one (the main app in debug mode but not run under the debugger) makes no difference, unfortunately. "Win offers to debug" only refers to the usual dialog of "Windows looking for a solution" and a Debug button at the bottom.

Comment: Hans, I edited the question a bit to include these details. No matter how I start the parts, the problem is that when it comes to actually debugging the access violation, the (otherwise seemingly correctly set up debugger, attached and running) refuses to debug, stating that it's unable to handle this exception.

This must be some specific problem here, not a general one because I did debug similar problems in other parts of the same application with success.

Answer (score 0):

I think I nailed it. `System::Diagnostics::Debugger::Launch()` can't be used in a situation like this. The only way is to use *Debug > Attach to Process* and set all code types carefully. I know I tried that earlier but some other settings were probably not in place yet. So, in addition to **all** of the above, only use this form of attaching the debugger, nothing else.